# New Android Project in MonoGame Error

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, monogame

I just installed MonoGame 3.0 Beta, and I thought I'd try and make a new android project in it, and was presented with this error message:
[image]

I can't actually find a way around this.

Does anyone have any more insight into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install Mono for Android ( http://android.xamarin.com/ ) before trying to create an MonoGame Android project? If you do not have the above compiler installed, then logically it won't allow you to create a project of that type. I hope this helps.